# How netty manage the health of Socket

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I am beginner in both Java Socket Programming and Netty. Currently , we have a application which uses a pure Java Socket Connection where we manage the health of socket by our own.

I wish to understand how netty manages sockets?
For how long the port will be open?
What will happen if socket connection is dropped?
How Netty is maintaining the tcp session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netty is completely transparent with respect to managing the underlying tcp socket details.

> For how long the port will be open?

Netty allows you to set SO_TIMEOUT on the channel - this is basically a tcp property that raises read timeout alerts and you can write code to respond to this and drop the connection if you desire so.

See [ChannelOptions](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOption.html)

> What will happen if socket connection is dropped?

If you use a SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler , then its `channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)` will be invoked.

See [SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.html)

> How Netty is maintaining the tcp session?

Not sure exactly what you mean but it basically is the same mechanics used in the a tcp protocol.

Comment: SO_TIMEOUT is a read timeout. It doesn't cause the connection to be dropped, and it wouldn't be observed by Netty anyway as it is in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP - corrected myself. Thanks for pointing out. Netty also has a blocking mode if one wants to use.

Comment: SO_TIMEOUT works only for the OIO transport, and Netty does not close a connection or raise any exceptions or alerts because of it.

Comment: @trustin - yes it is OIO i am referring too ( because NIO is non-blocking ). and if theres no alerts on SO_TIMEOUT whats the significance of allowing this option to be setup on the channel ?

Comment: Shorter SO_TIMEOUT is, for shorter duration it will wait for each `InputStream.read()`.  This is an important tuning parameter for OIO because `InputStream.read()` will block if there's nothing in the recv buffer.  The default is 1 second, which means `InputStream.read()` will wait at most for 1 second until it checks its task queue.